# Permission denied trying to erase laptop hard drive from live USB

Tags: permissions, sudo, io-redirection

I put an Ubuntu ISO on a USB drive, booted from that USB on my laptop, and then called

```
$ cat /dev/zero | pv > /dev/sda
```

to try to overwrite my laptop's hard drive (`sda`) with zeros.

I get the following error:

```
bash: /dev/sda: Permission denied
```

This error is raised regardless of whether I pre-pend my command with `sudo`.  Why am I getting this?  How do I circumvent this error?

(Could it have something to do with mounting/unmounting?  Full disclosure: I have already partially erased `sda`, but the erasure was interrupted midway -- I'm rerunning the command to make sure it is fully erased.)

**EDIT**

I was able to erase the hard drive using the disk utility GUI instead.  But I'm still curious whether it would have been possible to do it via the command line using the method I attempted first.

Answer (score 1):

Output redirection is done by shell, and non-root shell doesn't have access to `/dev/sda`. If you don't want to change to root shell, you can run the command with `sudo` and `tee`:

```
cat /dev/zero | pv | sudo tee /dev/sda
```

Answer (score -1):

See:

[Permission denied trying to erase laptop hard drive from live USB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389642/permission-denied-trying-to-erase-laptop-hard-drive-from-live-usb)

It worked for me, with `dd if=/dev/sda of= ... ...`

Try this: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
$ sudo -i
```

That will give you a root shell, that way it'll all run as root.